# Calling viewDidLoad while poping from a navigation class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

**Interview question:** For example, I have 3 classes A,B & C. I navigate from A -> B -> C, while pushing `viewDidLoad` function calls automatically and during popping `viewWillAppear` get called. But would it be possible to call my `viewDidLoad` function while popping?

Comment: You can call everything you want manually. But if standard methods are not good for you - may be you just put your code in the wrong method?

Comment: you mentioned in a comment to an answer that this is an interview question... perhaps what you want to know is not "is it possible to call" but "is it possible that it will be called", as opposed to "is it garanteed that `viewDidLoad` will never be called when popping"... is that your question?

Comment: Filipe: my question is, how can we call viewDidLoad while popping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Its not possible.Only viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear will be called by itself.You can call it manually.

All the best.

Comment: As far as the feasibility is concern... I know it can be done but don't know how :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the real need for it?

Comment: What is your purpose of calling viewDidLoad while poping ? can u explain?

Comment: write a method and put the code inside this method that you were planning to put inside viewDidLoad. Then call this method from viewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear. You can use a BOOL flag to determine the poping event if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The `viewDidLoad` method is called when the view just loaded. Then `viewWillAppear` is called by the navigation controller when it's about to display the view.
If you want some code to be executed when the view is about to be displayed, be it when it's being pushed or when the top one is being popped, it makes more sense to use the appropriate method `viewWillAppear` for that, instead of trying to call the `viewDidLoad` method at a time when it isn't appropriate.
Can't you just move whatever code you have in `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`?

If the question is just "how can we call viewDidLoad while popping?", then it's simple:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Just as a side note, if you have a view controller stack like A->B, it's possible that `viewDidLoad` will be called automatically on A when popping B if, while B was on top, the navigation controller unloaded A's view (if the app received a memory warning, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** call `viewDidLoad` manually, it's not designed to be handled this way. Use `viewWillAppear`, as other users already mentioned.

As for the question whether it may happen that `viewDidLoad` will be called upon popping from a higher view controller: I imagine that **may** happen when the device got a low memory warning and unloaded the view controllers further down in the navigation hierarchy. Then the OS has to reload the view, I haven't however tested this and it's possible that this will never happen. The OS only unloads views when they don't have a superview, I didn't check whether upon pushing, views down the hierarchy actually get removed from the hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

ViewDidLoad should be for view creation.
ViewWillAppear - for Data Interaction if Server Request is Asynchronous. like calling API or any functionality.or any functionality we like to call when view going to appear.

ViewDidAppear - for Data Interaction if Server Request is synchronous.

Comment: I don't think there's any relation between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods and any server request at all. You can use those methods for anything you want to execute at those particular moments in a view's life cycle. They have no particular relation to data interaction.

Comment: if  synchronous request is call in  viewWillAppear . i guess view wont appear till request complete :) .there is not necessary to do server interaction in viewWillAppear.but it is good to do

Comment: true, but that just means you shouldn't call synchronous requests while your trying to animate something. Doesn't mean that `viewWillAppear` is *for* asynchronous requests. `viewWillAppear` is for anything you want to do just before the view appears.